# How to call this secure webservice WDSL from Savon in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

I have some working PHP example (see below) for accessing a secure webservice. I am trying to access the webservice with Savon. First, I tried:

```
>> client = Savon::Client.new("https://secure.service.com/soa/soap/?WSDL")
=> #<Savon::Client:0x114053358 @wsdl=#<Savon::WSDL:0x1140532b8 @request=#<Savon::Request:0x1140532e0 @endpoint=#<URI::HTTPS:0x114053038 URL:https://secure.service.com/soa/soap/?WSDL>, @proxy=#<URI::Generic:0x114052fc0 URL:>>>, @request=#<Savon::Request:0x1140532e0 @endpoint=#<URI::HTTPS:0x114053038 URL:https://secure.service.com/soa/soap/?WSDL>, @proxy=#<URI::Generic:0x114052fc0 URL:>>>
```

First problem, SOAP actions seem to be empty:

```
>> client.wsdl.soap_actions
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
=> []
```

And trying to access the webservice with wsse credentials like this:

```
>> client = Savon::Client.new do |wsdl, http|
?>   wsdl.document = "https://secure.service.com/soa/soap/?WSDL"
>>   wsdl.wsse.credentials "user", "encrypted-md5-string"
>> end
```

results in:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

What could be taken from this working PHP example below in Ruby, to set some basic requests to the webservice?

PHP example:

```
$foo = "+++hashkey+++";

$authUser = "user";
$authPass = "password";

$passphrase = md5($foo.$authPass.".wsdl");

echo "User: ".$authUser."<br>";
echo "Passphrase: ".$foo.$authPass.".wsdl<br>";
echo "Digest Passphrase: ".$passphrase."<br>";

$soapClient = new SoapClient( "https://secure.service.com/soa/soap/?WSDL", 
     array( "exceptions"  => true,
            "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            "login" => $authUser,
            "password" => $passphrase));

$param = new stdClass();

$param->bankaccount = "1111111";
$param->bankcountry = "US";

$soaMethod = "SoaBank.getBank"; 
$soaParams = array($param);
$result = $soapClient->__soapCall($soaMethod, $soaParams);

print "<h1>Result</h1>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I found that the definition of the SOAP-ENV was causing the problems. It must actually be defined case-sensitive.

Comment: Also, the newer versions of Savon seem to have better support to address different SOAP envelope types

Answer (score 2):

For Savon 2 you can use `:ssl_verify_mode => :none`

```
Savon.client(:wsdl => 'https://blahService?wsdl', :ssl_verify_mode => :none)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off ssl verification:

```
    client = Savon::Client.new("http://wsdl") do
      http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none          
    end
```